# Ошибка CLion (Cmake, SFML)

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, clion

Ошибка: `CMake Error at cmake_modules/FindSFML.cmake:355 (message):
      Could NOT find SFML (missing: SFML_AUDIO_LIBRARY SFML_NETWORK_LIBRARY
      SFML_GRAPHICS_LIBRARY SFML_WINDOW_LIBRARY SFML_SYSTEM_LIBRARY)
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)`

---

### -Помогите! При попытке запуска данная ошибка! Что это может значить?

CmakeLists: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

```
         project(utitled6) 

         set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) 

         set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
         -IC:/SFML-2.4.2/include/SFML -LC:/SFML-2.4.2/lib") 

         set(SOURCE_FILES 
         main.cpp ) 

         set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules) 

         find_package(SFML 
         REQUIRED COMPONENTS Audio Network Graphics Window System)

         include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}) 

         add_executable(utitled6 
         main.cpp) 

         target_link_libraries(utitled6 sfml-audio sfml-network 
         sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)`
```

Comment: CMake файл в студию

Comment: Похвально, конечно, не сдаваться 11 дней. Но думаю если бы вы 1 раз оформили вопрос подробно (привели CMakeLists.txt, пути установки библиотек и т.д. - всё что может помочь), то уже давно бы получили ответ

Comment: @cpp questions, спасибо что похвалили за упорство :D . Но можно по теме. `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(utitled6)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -IC:/SFML-2.4.2/include/SFML -LC:/SFML-2.4.2/lib")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp )
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules)
find_package(SFML REQUIRED COMPONENTS Audio Network Graphics Window System)

include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(utitled6 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(utitled6 sfml-audio sfml-network sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)`

Comment: CmakeLists ^ ^ ^

Comment: Добавьте всё нужное в сам вопрос с помощью кнопки "править", в комментариях это сложно читать (заодно вопрос поднимите на главной)

Comment: А сама то библиотека установлена? И куда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

СВЕРШИЛОСЬ! Я всё-таки это сделал. Краткая инструкция:

### 1.Скачиваем MinGW_makeFiles_custom (https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/downloads/68260/mingw-get-setup.exe/).

### 2.В Clion заходим в File -> Settings -> Toolchain -> Выбираем вместо "Visual Studio" - "MinGW". (Оно автоматически найдет компиляторы).

3.Перезагружаем Clion и в CMakeLists.txt вставляем:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

set(PROJECT_NAME cpp1)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

set(SFML_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SFML-2.4.2")
set(SFML_ROOT ${SFML_DIR})
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${SFML_DIR}/cmake/Modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML 2 COMPONENTS system window graphics audio network REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

### Где `set(SFML_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SFML-2.4.2")` это путь к SFML, а cpp1 - это имя вашего проекта.

### 4.Перезагружаем (Reload Changes).

### 5.Готово!

Comment: Ну вот видите, всё получилось. Поздравляю :)

Answer (score 1):

Использую такой конфиг и всё работает. Зачем добавлять IC?

```
add_executable(sfml_test ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE) #SFML_STATIC

find_package(SFML 2.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS
             graphics window system audio)

include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(sfml_test ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Куда это запихнуть? Я и так и сяк, но всё равно ничего. Я бы оставил ошибку, но кол-во символов не позволяет

Comment: Я имею ввиду, в какую часть файла CmakeLists мне надо вставить то, что вы предложили мне как вариант решения моей проблем. Я умоляю вас указать мне куда мне нужно вставить это.